# Why can we write a volume integral $ \int_V dV$ as $\int_V dS dg/|\nabla g(x)| $ where $g(x)=0$ represents the surface?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I read that we can do the following in the appendix of a book on seismic imaging:
If $g(x) = 0$ represents the surface of some bounded domain then we can write
$$
\int_V dV = \int_V dS dg/|\nabla g(x)|
$$
where $dS$ is the differential surface area on the level surface(s) described by the condition $g(x) = \text{constant}$.

I don't see how this can be derived? In particular, how does the magnitude of the gradient of $g$ arise in the denominator?

Comment: This is stated on page 396 of "Mathematics of multidimensional seismic imaging migration and inversion" by Norman Bleistein.

Comment: I would write it as $\int_V |\nabla g(x)| dV  =  \int (\int_{g^{-1}(t)} dS) dt$. This is the coarea formula for which references may be found in the wikipedia page.